# html5 - how to disable select widget wheel on iphone and use the normal select

Tags: html, iphone, select, widget

Actually I develop a web app in html5/php/css/javascript for my mobile devices. (I'm a beginner) I have an "onclick" function on my "option" but with native select widget of devices it's not working.
Is it possible to disable select widget ?

```
    <select class="theme" name="newtheme">
    <option id="white" class="white" onclick="createCookie('theme','white',7)">white</option>
  <option id="white" class="white" onclick="createCookie('theme','white',7)">white</option>
    </select>
```

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 1):

With jQuery you could use :

```
$("#ThemeSelector").on('change', function(event){
 // event contains the data from the selected line
 createCookie('theme','white',7);
});
```

Your HTML should look like this:

```
   <select id="ThemeSelector" class="theme" name="newtheme">
    <option class="white">white</option>
  <option class="white">white</option>
    </select>
```

ID's should be unique!

Answer (score 0):

When developing mobile web apps you should try to avoid using "onClick" and rather use the "tap" events. They perform better and will make your UI more responsive. (They also cause less trouble - e.g. clicks do not always fire on different mobile browsers in some scenarios).

But of course @Robbert 's suggestion to use the "change" event should also work fine.

I just wanted to point that out to, as you said, you're a beginner.